# how to authorize and authenticate the same type of user at diffrent permission?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identity

I'm working on part of a project about authorize and authenticate.so,but I've problem in the the same type of user with different permission.for example,

```
UserPermission Table
------------------------
UserId(int) //this is a AUTO INCREMENT primary key    
UserBasicInformation(bool)     
UserOperation(bool)     
UserEntrance(bool)     
UserExit(bool)     
UserReport(bool)
AdminBasicInformation(bool)
AdminOperation(bool)
AdminSettings(bool)
UserPermissionId(int) // in this field I've kept key of users from UserDefs table
UserTitle(nvarchar)


UserDefs (brief)
--------------------------
UserId ///this is a AUTO INCREMENT primary key
UserType(int) //1,2
UserName(nvarchar) // admin,user
UserTitle(nvarchar) // alex,sara,....

UserId    UserType    UserName    UserTitle
--------------------------------------------
1             1           Admin     alex
2             1           Admin     sara
3             2           user      steve
4             2           user      nicolas
```

this is **UserPermision table** that I populate for better understand.

```
UserId   UserBasicInformation   UserOperation   UserEntrance   UserExit   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1               0                     0               0            0  
2               0                     0               0            0 
3               1                     1               1

UserReport     AdminBasicInformation    AdminOperation     AdminSettings
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 0                   1                        1                   0
 0                   0                        1                   1
 0                   0                        0                   0  

UserPermissionId     UserTitle      
-------------------------------
1                       alex 
1                       sara
2                       steve
```

if you take a look at userDefs table I have a two admins or two users but they are different permission in UserPermission table.but now,I don't know how to implement it.some people said me I use sessions what is your idea about it? in fact,I will read userpermission table.

Comment: Use an existing framework - see https://asp.net/identity. Out of the box give you claims and roles support. Better than trying to roll your own